# Extract text between URL with Java

Tags: java

I want to extract from this URL: "https://www.newhomesource.com/community/az/cave-creek/galloway-ridge-by-k-hovnanian-homes/148397" the text "k-hovnanian-homes"

The thing is that I manage to obtain this String: "k-hovnanian-homes/148397" but I can't remove the /148397. Is there a way I can remove it?

Here is what I have

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public void VerifyURL(){
    String URL= "https://www.newhomesource.com/community/az/cave-creek/galloway-ridge-by-k- 
    hovnanian-homes/148397";
   
    String Final = URL.substring(URL.indexOf("by-") + 3);
    System.out.println(Final);

 }
```

Also the numbers after the "/" can change so take that in count

I'm Selenium WebDriver and TestNG so that's why the imports :)

Update: Another URL example could be: https://www.newhomesource.com/community/tn/lebanon/hampton-chase-legacy-collection-by-beazer-homes/152012

Comment: `URL.substring(URL.indexOf("by-") + 3).split("/")[0]` remove anything after `/`

Comment: In order to answer this, we'd need more details. What is the pattern of the URL? Are the trailing characters always numbers? Always n characters long? Could there be more characters after that? A few more examples would be very helpful.

Comment: @blackbrandt I updated the post with another URL. Mostly there are 6 numbers after the "/" and mostly all the url changes except for the by-

Comment: Provide both start and end index in substring method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **lastIndexOf**

```
 String URL= "https://www.newhomesource.com/community/az/cave-creek/galloway-ridge-by-k-hovnanian-homes/148397";

 String Final = URL.substring(URL.indexOf("by-") + 3,URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
 System.out.println(Final);
```